# Split array into dynamic array and return ptr

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I have a problem. I have to divide array into dynamic array and return pointer with parameter.

When I try to run this code, I get **(interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)** this message. I think it is something with my pointers. But I don't even get any warnings, I don't know where to look else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int splitData(int data[], int size, int splitPlace, int **firstArray);

int main() {

    int data[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int size = 6;
    int *ptr = NULL;
    int n = splitData(data, size, 3, &ptr);
    printf("%d", n);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("[%d]", ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int splitData(int data[], int size, int splitPlace, int **firstArray)
{

    *firstArray = (int *)malloc(splitPlace * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < splitPlace; ++i)
    {
        *firstArray[i] = data[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have the precedence wrong with *firstArray[i]. You need (*firstArray)[i]. Clearer might be to allocate "int *new_array = malloc(...); *firstArray = new_array. Then use new_array in your loop body.

Comment: Thank you. I changed *firstArray[i] to (*firstArray)[i]. I know it was the problem now

Comment: I've added that as an answer, which you can accept if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the precedence wrong with *firstArray[i]. You need (*firstArray)[i].

Clearer might be to allocate

```
int *new_array = malloc(...);
*firstArray = new_array.
```

Then use new_array in your loop body.